# htaccess is redirecting to "webroot" every time that a request without end trailling is done

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.3

I have the follow project structure:

```
public_html/
|- app/
   |- webroot/
      |- news -> symlink to ../../news/webroot/
      |- .htaccess (see code 1)
   |- .htaccess (see code 2)
|- news/
   |- webroot/
```

.htaccess 1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(img|css|js|fonts)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I request `/news` (as a pretty URL managed by the framework), the request is redirected to `/webroot/news/` by apache, instead of load the news. I can't find what is wrong, what is your suggestion?

So, if I click: `news` the page is redirected to `/webroot/news/`. If I click: `news/` the page is redirected to `/news/`
(Using subdomain inside the domain of cPanel)

Comment: If your subdomain points to public_html/app, then you should remove the symlink public_html/app/webroot/news, otherwise Apache finds it and does not pass the URL to index.php.
Also, the default .htaccess that comes with CakePHP has no RewriteBase option.

Comment: @savedario My app ponts to public_html/app/webroot. This is not the default htaccess. Symlink will not match and `RewriteCond` rule, so, will be served as a normal request as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**public_html/app/.htaccess**

```
Deleted file
```

**public_html/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(img|css|js|fonts)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Subdomain pointed to **public_html/app/webroot/**

**SOLVED.**

Answer (score 1):

Turn directory trailing slash off in your root .htaccess since `mod_dir` adds a trailing slash after `mod_dir`. As a last rule add trailing slash back again internally:

**.htaccess 1:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]

    # add trailing slash for directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```